# How to import automatically interface .class file into client in RMI?

Tags: java, rmi

I'm very to RMI ,so my question maybe a bit misunderstanding.

I'm going to describe my problem now.

When I develop a RMI application on Eclipse:

Server-side:

1. Create a project just to define all Interfaces (extends Remote) that my app need.
2. Create a project for implementing above Interfaces.
3. Create a server project and register remote object to RMIRegistry.

Client-side

1. Create a client project. And my problem here:

   a.    CalInterface c = (CalInterface)r.lookup("mycalserver");

Because the CalInterface is not in client project, so I need to build and copy CalInterface .class to client project (by adding external class folder). It works fine.

My question is:

1. How to import automatically in client project?.
2. Is CalInterface.class a stub role in client?
3. Is my approach fine for developing a RMI app?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> Server-side:
>
> Create a project just to define all Interfaces (extends Remote) that my app need.

No. This should be a separate project that is shared by the server and client projects. It must contain not only the remote interfaces but also any application classes that the remote interfaces depend on, and so on recursively until closure.

> Create a project for implementing above Interfaces.
>      Create a server project and register remote object to RMIRegistry.

You don't need both those, you can combine them into one server project, and add the shared project to it.

> Client-side
>
> Create a client project.

And add the shared project to it.

> My question is:
>
> How to import automatically in client project?.

See above.

> Is CalInterface.class a stub role in client?

No, it is a remote interface. The *object you get* from `lookup()` is a remote stub that *implements* that interface, but the mechanics of that are automatic and don't concern you.

> Is my approach fine for developing a RMI app?

No, see above.

Comment: Thank you but how to import shared project automatically?. What will happen if I run client project on another Pc? Is codebase what I should looking for?

Comment: I can't advise you on how to share projects in Eclipse but there must be a way. The result is that the client is compiled with the shared project in its CLASSPATH, and deployed with the shared .jar file.

Comment: Oh, so I dont need to worry about CalInterface.class because it's a part of client project?

Comment: It's part of the client project by being part of the shared project that is included in the client project.